# C++ error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token { inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, include-guards

I have a superclass Letter.h

```
#ifndef LETTER_H  //I have tried ifdef but it give me list of undefined reference 
and variables out of scope 
#define LETTER_H


#include "A.h"

using namespace std;


class Letter{
//variables are declared in protected

public:
        Letter();
        Letter(string,bool);
            };
            #endif
```

I have a sub class A.h

```
 #ifndef A_H
    #define A_H
    #include "Letter.h"
    using namespace std;



 class A: public Letter{
    //variables are declared in private
    public:
        A();
        A(string, bool, int, int, double);   
 };
       #endif
```

In my Letter.cpp I have `#include Letter.h` 
In my A.cpp I have `#include A.h` and `#include Letter.h`

In my A.cpp

```
   A::A(string ShapeName, bool warpspace, int xval, int yval, double areas):Letter(ShapeName, warpspace)
{
    xVal = xval;
    yVal = yval;
    area = areas;
}
```

In my letter.cpp

```
Letter::Letter (string name, bool containsWarpSpace)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->containsWarpSpace = containsWarpSpace;
}
```

when I compile the above like this: g++ Letter.cpp Letter.h A.cpp A.h it gives me  `error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token  {`

I know letter is the parent class it does not need to include the sub class but however when I remove the #include square.h it gives me relocation invalid symbol index error .

Is the guard and header files properly included this way?

Lets say if i haven't wrote anything to inherit from Letter yet , will the compiler still allow me to compile?

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon ";" at the end of declaration of class A

Comment: Aren't you missing something when ending the `A` class? You have the closing brace `}`, but shouldn't there be something else?

Comment: @10100111001 Spoiler alert

Comment: Also, don't ever use `using` to import names from or namespaces themselves. Name collisions will ensue sooner or later. If not in your own code, someone using your code will get really really *<choose your favorite word for a state of anger and frustration>*.

Comment: @10100111001 I have added it in , I forgot to type it in sorry . the org code was with " ; "

Comment: @forgivenprog33442 There's no way to diagnose your error from your example code. Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces it.

Comment: The code is long with accessors and mutators and calcluations but i haven't wrote anything to inherit the parent class functions and variables , but is there anything wrong with the above example first? am i doing it correctly? I don't wanna post a code overlapping  issues with the #include guards and #include header files . i need to make sure the headers and guards are correctly included @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ have edited to make it minimal